# Tomcat 6 - The requested resource ... is not available

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, web.xml, stripes

I am trying to start developing with Java and the Stripes Framework. I have the following in my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<web-app version="2.4"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    >

      <filter>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
          <param-value>
            pdapm.action
          </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
          <param-value>
            pdapm.extensions, org.stripesbook.reload.extensions
          </param-value>
        </init-param>   
      </filter>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DynamicMappingFilter</filter-class> 
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>   
      </filter-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
      </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**I am receiving the error:**

```
The requested resource ... is not available.
```

Is there anything I need to add or anything I should try to fix associated with tomcat. I used the tomcat addon to xampp. I am a beginner so it may have been a simple mistake or skipped step. I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

```
[21:44:14] WARN net.sourceforge.stripes.util.ResolverUtil - Could not examine class
'pdapm/action/BaseActionBean.class' due to a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError 
with message: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class 
pdapm.action.BaseActionBean) 

[21:44:14] WARN net.sourceforge.stripes.util.ResolverUtil - Could not examine class 
'pdapm/action/HomeActionBean.class' due to a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError 
with message: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class 
pdapm.action.HomeActionBean)
```

Comment: [21:44:14] WARN  net.sourceforge.stripes.util.ResolverUtil  - Could not examine class 'pdapm/action/BaseActionBean.class' due to a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError with message: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class pdapm.action.BaseActionBean)

[21:44:14] WARN  net.sourceforge.stripes.util.ResolverUtil  - Could not examine class 'pdapm/action/HomeActionBean.class' due to a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError with message: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class pdapm.action.HomeActionBean)

Comment: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5144147

Comment: Thanks for the link but read the comment on ZZ Coder's answer. Any ideas?

Comment: @Smithers: FYI: you can edit your question to contain a formatted error message, after the fact.  Much better than comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means your stripes library is compiled with a newer Java than the Tomcat's JVM. Java is not forward-compatible. Say your Tomcat runs under Java 5. It can't load classes compiled with Java 6.

Upgrade the JRE on your system.

Comment: The JRE on my system is the latest version and is being pointed to by my JAVA_HOME environment variable. However, the Tomcat addon to xampp has a jre included in the installation and is using an old version. I ran tomcatw6.exe and tried to change it to point to the new JVM, but then I could no longer start tomcat. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think ZZ Coder could be right did you check what complier compliance level your project is targeted at and if it's set to 1.6 (Java 6); set it to 1.5 (or whatever Java version your Server is running in) -rebuild and deploy and see what happens.